# Gradually increase speed of SpriteKit objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a simple game with stones "raining" from top to bottom of the screen.

I am working with SpriteKit and I would like the stones to increase their speed by time like it would be level 1 level 2 level 3 and so on. Maximum speed should be easy to implement then.

I have a variable "speed" for the speed of the stones.

I think I could just use a timer and after 5s speed = 2, after 10s speed = 5, and so on, but I'm not sure how I can implement that.

EDIT:

I'm moving my stones with this:

```
-(void) moveStones{
SKAction *actionMove = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-5 duration:0.25];
for(SKSpriteNode *stone in self.stones)
{
    [stone runAction:actionMove];
}
}
```

And in my viewDidLoad I have the timer:

```
 moveStones = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(moveStones) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

If the timer does not respect the view, is there a way to move them without that timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are moving stones by physics, then after the stone is spawned you should apply an stronger impulse/force (based on current level) If you are moving them with actions, then change the speed of action, or lower the moveDuration. If you are moving stones by changing its position in update: method, then change the value which indicates how much points a sprite should move in every update call.

To implement time based actions like spawning stones or to decide when to change  the speed of spawned nodes, you should use SKAction, or update: method and its passed parameter called `currentTime`. Using `NSTimer` for any of this in SpriteKit can lead to problems, because NSTimer don't respect view's , scene's or node's paused state, so its better to avoid using it.

Here is an example on how you can do what you want with `SKAction`. In this example you can see how to:

- track the number of seconds passed
- maintain the info about current level
- spawn node with random delay
- stop spawning nodes by using action key
- and probably some more

**GameScene.h**

```
 #import "GameScene.h"

@interface GameScene()

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger counter;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger level;

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKLabelNode *debug;

@end

@implementation GameScene




// Here we set initial values of counter and level. Debug label is created here as well.
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    self.counter = 0;
    self.level = 1;

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor grayColor];


    self.debug = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"ArialMT"];
    self.debug.fontColor = [SKColor purpleColor];
    self.debug.fontSize = 30.0f;
    self.debug.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    self.debug.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Counter : [ %ld ], Level [ %ld ]", (long)self.counter,(long)self.level];
    [self addChild:self.debug];


}

//Method to start a timer. SKAction is used here to track a time passed and to maintain current level
-(void)startTimer{

    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self; //make a weak reference to scene to avoid retain cycle

    SKAction *block = [SKAction runBlock:^{

        weakSelf.counter++;

        //Maintaining level

        if(weakSelf.counter < 5){
            //level 1
            weakSelf.level = 1;

        }else if(weakSelf.counter >=5 && weakSelf.counter <10){
            //level 2

            weakSelf.level = 2;

        }else{
            //level 3
            weakSelf.level = 3;

        }

        weakSelf.debug.text =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Counter : [ %ld ], Level [ %ld ]", (long)weakSelf.counter,(long)weakSelf.level];

    }];



    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:1], block]]] withKey:@"counting"];
}

//Method for stopping timer and reseting everything to default state.
-(void)stopTimer{

    if([self actionForKey:@"counting"]){

        [self removeActionForKey:@"counting"];
    }

    self.counter = 0.0f;
    self.level = 1;

    self.debug.text =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Counter : [ %ld ], Level [ %ld ]", (long)self.counter,(long)self.level];

}

//Get current speed based on time passed (based on counter variable)
-(CGFloat)getCurrentSpeed{

    if(self.counter < 5){
        //level 1

        return 1.0f;
    }else if(self.counter >=5 && self.counter <10){
        //level 2

        return 2.0f;
    }else{
        //level 3

        return 3.0f;
    }

}
//Method which stop generating stones, called in touchesBegan
-(void)stopGeneratingStones{

    if([self actionForKey:@"spawning"]){
        [self removeActionForKey:@"spawning"];
    }

}

//You can use this useful method to generate random float between two numbers
- (CGFloat)randomFloatBetween:(CGFloat)smallNumber and:(CGFloat)bigNumber {
    CGFloat diff = bigNumber - smallNumber;
    return (((CGFloat) (arc4random() % ((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1)) / RAND_MAX) * diff) + smallNumber;
}

//Method for generating stones, you run this method when you want to start spawning nodes (eg. didMoveToView or when some button is clicked)

-(void)generateStones{


    SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:2 withRange:0.5]; //randomizing delay time

    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self; //make a weak reference to scene to avoid retain cycle


    SKAction *block = [SKAction runBlock:^{


        SKSpriteNode *stone = [weakSelf spawnStoneWithSpeed:[weakSelf getCurrentSpeed]];
        stone.zPosition = 20;


        [weakSelf addChild:stone];

    }];


    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[delay, block]]] withKey:@"spawning"];
}

//Returns stone with moving action added. Inside, you set standard things, like size, texture, physicsbody, name and position of a stone
-(SKSpriteNode*)spawnStoneWithSpeed:(CGFloat)stoneSpeed{

    CGSize stoneSize = CGSizeMake(30,30); //you can randomize size here

    CGPoint stonePosition = CGPointMake( [self randomFloatBetween:0.0f and:self.frame.size.width], CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)); //you can randomize position here

    SKSpriteNode *stone = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:stoneSize];

    stone.name = @"stone"; //this helps if you want to enumerate all stones by name later on in your game

    stone.position = stonePosition;

    SKAction *move = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-200 duration:3.25];

    //one way to change speed

    move.speed = stoneSpeed;


    SKAction *moveAndRemove = [SKAction sequence:@[move, [SKAction removeFromParent]]];

    [stone runAction:moveAndRemove withKey:@"moving"]; //access this key if you want to stop movement


    return stone;

}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    //just a simple way to start and stop a game
    if(![self actionForKey:@"counting"]){

        [self startTimer];

        [self generateStones];

    }else{

        [self stopTimer];

        [self stopGeneratingStones];

    }

}



@end
```

And here is the result:

[image: spawning]

Now its up to you how you will set the speed. You can play with that.

If you want to skip some parts, or you don't know where to look, the heart of everything is in method called `generateStones` That is how you can spawn stones with a time delay by using SKActions. The another important method is  `spawnStoneWithSpeed:` where you can see how to manipulate with speed of an action.

Another way to affect on node's moving speed, as I said, is to change duration parameter of method `moveByX: duration:`

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Robin I could try, just a min :) You should always show a problematic code example which shows what have you tried so far. That way its more likely that you will get better answer because people will know what the issue really is.

Comment: @Robin At first look, the code can seem complicated, but its not. Those are just ordinary things, and there are a lot of ways to do it. Go easily through code, see comments, and if you have questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I think first , I will be fine. I didn't check all the code but it looks pretty good , thank you very much. Ill have more time to check tomorrow if it works for me :).

Comment: One more question maybe , could you have a short look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610258/detect-contact-when-both-physics-bodies-are-dynamic-sprite-kit-objective-c