# detect contact when both physics bodies are dynamic sprite kit objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

is it possible to detect a contact and let the object pass the other ?  Because I want to increase a variable when they pass each other.

I made both phyisicsbodies dynamic, then they pass but didBeginContact is not working anymore then.

Thanks

EDIT:

Okay , so everything is working when I don't have the bodies dynamic. I have a BottomEdgeBody which I use to detect when the raining stones passed my player and then it increases the Score. So, if nothing is dynamic, my stones stay on top of the bottomEdge but I want them to fall through it.

Some Code:

in didBeginContact

```
if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bottomEdgeCategory)
{
    self.scoring = self.scoring +1;
    [self.scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %ld", (long)self.scoring]];
}
if(contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == bottomEdgeCategory)
{
    self.scoring = self.scoring +1;
    [self.scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %ld", (long)self.scoring]];

}
```

If i make stone.physicsBody.dynamic = NO; and same for the bottomEdge, they pass themselves but the score is not increased anymore.

Comment: not sure that I fully understand the part "didBeginContact" is not working anymore." Do you know how to set properly category, contact and collision bit masks? Have you set physicsWorld.delegate properly ? Some code would be useful... Remember? ;)

Comment: I edited my post, I hope it is understandable

Comment: If you want to register contact, at least one body has to be dynamic, that's why score is not increased. So, if I understand you well, you want to register contact without having collisions between bodies ? If that's the case, just set physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0 on both bodies.

Comment: Yes thank you that was it!! I gotta go now, tomorrow Ill try the level thing :).

Answer (score 1):

Okay thank you, I just settled the collision Bit mask of the Stone and the BottomEdge to 0, then it is working properly